# Remove & and Whitespace in URL with preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am trying to remove Whitespaces and & in a URL and replace it with a -. So far the following works:

```
preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $page->label) // whitepace gets replaced with -    
preg_replace('/\&/', '-', $page->label) // & gets replaced with -
```

I would like to have this in one line, but I am not able to combine the 2. Can anyone help?
Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should keep it all nicely in one line.

```
$output = preg_replace('/\s+|&/', '-', $page->label);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $test = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $page->label);  
 $final_output = preg_replace('/\&/', '-', $test);
```

Try like this

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace( '/[&]|\s+/', '-', $page->label );
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
$output = preg_replace('/([\s+|\&])/', '-', $page->label);
```

Answer (score -1):

if you use Zend Framework, maybe [Zend View Escaspe](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.scripts.html#zend.view.scripts.escaping) is better.