# Removing extra whitespaces from url

Tags: php, apache

I am using this code

```
$db_cat_idval = $srowcat_mst['prodcatm_name'];

if (($db_cat_idval == $db_cat_id) or ($db_cat_idval == $db_lnk_cat_id) or ($db_cat_idval == $catone_id)) {
    if ($rqst_txtsrchval == '') {
        echo "<li class='navactive'>";
    } else {
        echo "<li>";
    }
} else {
    echo "<li>";
}

echo "<a href='sub-products?catname=$db_cat_idval'>$srowcat_mst[prodcatm_name]</a></li>";
```

thus on getting the value from database i get the URL like:

> public_html/sub-products?catname=Salwar Kameez .

I want to remove the extra space between Salwar Kameez and all other variables in the databse. 
Its is possible? Any help can be of great assistance.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9430274/remove-and-whitespace-in-url-with-preg-replace.

Comment: You could also use `str_replace(" ", "", $srowcat_mst[prodcatm_name])` while generating your url.

Comment: You could leave the space in and just urlencode() it. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Answer (score 2):

You should be using [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/urlencode) and [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars):

```
printf('<a href="sub-products?catname=%s">%s</a></li>',
    urlencode($db_cat_idval),
    htmlspecialchars($srowcat_mst[prodcatm_name], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')
));
```